# Find file directory after using os.expanduser (python)

Tags: python, directory

my program creates a log file on the users desktop using:

```
file = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Log.txt"), 'a')
```

But later I need to send the log file back to myself using MIME. To send a file it needs the the file directory but I do not know how to find that?   I tried doing this:

```
filename='(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Log.txt"), 'a')'
```

But this does not work. Is there another way to do this? If there is then please give an example since I am a beginner and don't really know what im doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this one? See if it works.

```
directory=os.path.dirname(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Log.txt"))
```

if you want absolute path try

```
fullpath=os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Log.txt"))
```

more convenient functions here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Comment: permission denied :  \ `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\mikur/Desktop'`.

Comment: Oh, fullpath=os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Log.txt")) worked, thanks.